# Imagen con archivo invalido

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery, signature

Estoy usando `signature_pad.js` para guardar una firma en la base de datos, pero la imagen que guarda es una imagen inválida.

les dejo el código:

```js
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener("submit", function(e)
{
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  var image = ctx.toDataURL("image/png"); // Agregar "image/png" aquí
  document.getElementById('base64').value = "data:image/png;" + image; // Agregar "data:image/png;" aquí
}, false);

document.getElementById('borrar').addEventListener("click", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  document.getElementById('base64').value = '';
}, false);

if(document.getElementById('base64').value == ''){
  alert("No hay firma");
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="base64" value="" id="base64">
<div id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad" >
<label class="" for="">Firma:</label>
<div class="signature-pad--body">
<canvas style="width: 640px; height: 420px; border: 1px black solid; " id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
</div>
<button id="borrar">Borrar</button>
```

**PHP**

```
$folderPath = "upload/";
$img = $_POST['base64'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$fileData = base64_decode($img);
$fileName = $folderPath . uniqid().'.png';
file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData);
```

Después hago en `INSERT` en la base, hasta ahí todo bien, pero la imagen que me guarda en la carpeta `UPLOAD` es un archivo invalido.

Así se ve la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que podría estar pasando.

Comment: Favor poner un ejemplo reproducible [MRE]

Comment: Ahi agregue el JS que faltaba, no se puede reproducir php por aca

Comment: Mira he colocado tu código en un snippet, da errores (falta el form), luego si agregas el form no hace nada, porque falta la librería que indicas que usas. Tienes que colocar todo lo necesario para reproducir el problema hasta el punto del PHP.

Comment: No me permite poner el código completo, dice que es demasiado código

Comment: @Yussef jamas podra colocar un EMV teniendo en cuenta que se trata de PHP y el snipped de SOes no ejecuta php... tampo permite subir archivos...

Comment: @SidneyAlan-DesignerProgra aqui el problema es que tienes que aprender a depurar el codigo, estas 100% seguro que la imagen viaja de tu front a tu backend???

Comment: La imagen si viaje, se hago un echo a la imagen me muestra upload/63ebe0f397b70.png no se que pasa que esta guardando mal

Comment: ¿Mandas la imagen por `$_POST` y no por [`$_FILES`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php)?

Comment: Si, es correcto lo envío por _POST[base64]